# Generalization of the Inverse Function Theorem

Tags: smooth-manifolds, inverse-function-theorem

This is exercise 10 on page 19 in Guillemin/Pollack Differential Topology.

> Let $f : X \to Y$ be a smooth map which is one-to-one on some compact
>   submanifold $Z$ of $X$. Moreover, let $df_p$ be nonsingular for all $p
>  \in Z$. Then there exists some neighbourhood $U$ of $Z$ in $X$ such
>   that $f\vert_U$ is one-to-one.

Towards a contradiction, assume that $f$ is not injective on any neighbourhood of $Z$. Now the hint states that we should construct two sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ in $X$ converging to some $z \in Z$ such that $f(x_n) = f(y_n)$. So since Guillemin/Pollack only work with $\mathbb{R}^n$, I thought we could consider the neighbourhoods $$U_\varepsilon := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \text{dist}(x,X) < \varepsilon\}$$ Now  choosing $\varepsilon = 1/n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ yields two sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ such that $f(x_n) = f(y_n)$. But I do not quite see how these sequences should converge (or at least subsequences) to a common point $z \in Z$. So my questions are:

- Is my choice of the sequences right?
- Is it possible to generalize this result to arbitrary manifolds, i.e. not involving Euclidean spaces? I mean the definition of $U_\varepsilon$ can be adapted by equipping $M$ with a Riemannian metric.

Comment: Each sequence will  have a convergent subsequence converging to some point in $Z$. Since $f$ is one-to-one and the images of the (possibly two) limits coincide by continuity, the are the same. And yes, a similar statement is true in general.

Comment: @Thomas But the points $x_n$ and $y_n$ in my construction may not lie in $Z$ only in $U_\varepsilon$? So I cannot apply sequence compactness.

Comment: A compact subset of a locally compact set has a compact neighbourhood. Choose compact neighbourhoods $V(z)$ for each $z\in Z$. Then the interiors $U(z)$ of these neighbourhoods cover $Z$ and since $Z$ is compact finitely many $U(z_1), \ldots U(z_n)$ will do. The union of the corresponding finitely many $V(z_i)$ is compact as the finite union of compact sets.

Comment: @Thomas And how exactly can I make sure that for some $\varepsilon$, $U_\varepsilon$ lies in the union of the $V(z_i)$'s?

Comment: You can either show that this is true if $\varepsilon$ is small enough or replace your neighbourhoods with your neighbourhoods intersected with the $V(z_i)$ in the first place.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks a lot!